# ReactJS, props between child and parent in render loop

Tags: reactjs

I have this passing `props` code between child and its parent:

**Parent.js**

```
const defaultState = {
  canOperate: false,
  // among other states
};

const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);

// this technique is for avoiding some re-renders in some occasions, I'm using a lot of this way to set the
// state in this Parent component, but isn't working on this case
const handleCanOperate = (value: boolean) => {
  setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    canOperate: value
  }));
};

<ChildComponent
  onCanOperate={handleCanOperate}
/>
```

**Child.js**

```
// from props I have: onCanOperate

useEffect(() => {
  const handleCanOperate = (canOperate: boolean) => onCanOperate(canOperate);

  if (data) {
    handleCanOperate(false);
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      isDisabled: true
    }));
  } else {
    setState(s => ({
      ...state,
      isDisabled: false
    }));
    handleCanOperate(true);
  }
}, [data, onCanOperate]);
```

With this approach I get a loop, but if in the parent I do this change there is no problem:

Parent that works:

```
const defaultState = {
  // other states
};

const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);
const [canOperate, setCanOperate] = useState(false);


<ChildComponent
  onCanOperate={setCanOperate}
/>
```

I don't want to use two setters for `state` in the **Parent** component, that's why I put a handler to call the already working `setState`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your loop is caused by the `handleCanOperate` function which gets redefined on re-render (when the state changes). This gets passed down to your child, which reruns the logic in your `useEffect` hook because it thinks `onCanOperate` has changed.

---

This also explains why it works when you place your handler in it's own state. React state is memoized and doesn't reinitialise on re-renders.

To fix this you could memoize your `handleCanOperate` so it doesn't reinitialise every re-render by wrapping it around a [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook. This hook works similarly to the `useEffect` hook and will only re-initialise your callback when a value in it's dependency array changes.

---

Your parent would look something like this:

```js
const defaultState = {
  canOperate: false,
  // among other states
};

const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);

const handleCanOperate = useCallback((value: boolean) => {
  setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    canOperate: value
  }));
}, []);

<ChildComponent
  onCanOperate={handleCanOperate}
/>
```

I haven't tested this, but I do believe this would fix your issue.